# Notations for sum of entries in a matrix

Tags: matrices, notation

I came across $\sum_{i,j = 1}^na_{ij}$, and I was wondering if this means $\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j= 1}^na_{ij}$ (sum of every element) or $\sum_{i = j = 1}^na_{ij}$ (sum of diagonal)?

Comment: The formeer (by what might be called abuse of notation). If the latter were intended, one wouldwrite $\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ii}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must read it "sum of the $a_{ij}$'s as $i$ and $j$ run simultaneously and independently between $1$ and $n$". So it is the sum of every entries of the matrix.